# Displaying the averaged values of the speedometer android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have written a code for a speedometer in eclipse. It is working fine. I am trying to display the averaged values of the speed that the speedometer is measuring and while i try to do that i am failing because i am not finding the right approach on how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        this.onLocationChanged(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        if (location == null) {

            tv.setText("0.0");
        } else {

            float nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
            tv.setText(nCurrentSpeed + "");


        }

    }
```

How can i do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's failing?  Are you not getting any values?  Are you getting the wrong value?  We can't tell from your question.

Comment: I am not finding the right logic to do it bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public float average(float[] v) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    return sum / v.length;
}
```

This is how you use:

```
float[] nSpeed = new float[] {1,2,3};
System.out.println(average(nSpeed));
```

Comment: Trying it, but how do i display the resultant of the value generated by your code. P.S i am replacing v by nCurrentSpeed, am i doing it right?

Comment: I haven't tried your code but I think you need to convert the float value of nCurrentSpeed to double first, like this `double d = nCurrentSpeed `  and then use the method above `average(d)`

Comment: Trying and failing badly, Bro if you could please try it for my case it would be a huge help from your side.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, what do you mean by failing? What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: I am really not understanding this actually since i have been doing stuff more on the animation side in android programming. The method you explained i get it but i am unable to implement it according to my case.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75620/discussion-between-aleem-ahmed-and-m-y).